# From a Kantian perspective, could any aspect of this situation be considered moral?

Tags: ethics, kant

**The situation:** Let's say two teams are competing in a research competition. The rules require the teams to have members that have never competed in this competition in the past. The director of Team A found out that the director of Team B recruited someone who had competed in the competition in the past, and then he also recruited a past member for his own team. Only the director of Team A knows about this and did not inform his team mates for their own good. He did not want them to stress that they might get disqualified.

---

The way I see it is that what the director of Team A did goes completely against the Kantian definition of morality. I do not see any aspect of this situation that could be considered moral. Was it moral that the director of Team A kept it a secret? No, because such secrecy to benefit oneself is not something that can be made a universal law. Am I wrong?